# How to get the provisioning state of the azure resource deployment through invoke command (REST API)

Tags: azure, powershell, provisioning, invoke-command

Deployment of webjobs in a web app

```
$t=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Headers $Headers -UserAgent $userAgent -Method PUT -InFile $f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following Azure Rest API to get the deployment status of Azure Web App resources.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/getdeployment

There's a nice "Try it" section, where you can play this API, live with your subscription.

[image]

**Edit 1**
Please follow here on how to call Azure Rest APIs via Powershell:

https://blog.tekspace.io/access-azure-rest-api-using-powershellhttps://blog.tekspace.io/access-azure-rest-api-using-powershell/

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Hi, how can I get the `id` means `Deployment ID` in request parameters?

Comment: @SunnySharma I would like to do this in power shell

Comment: @JoyWang: You will get a deployment Id in response to Azure Resource deployment request.

Comment: @twinklehema: check out the link I've added in my answer.

Comment: @SunnySharma I was speaking about the provisioning status that we see in the arm deployment how do we get it ? What does a invoke command return I found it as a hash table of contents

Comment: @twinklehema: please share what you've tried so far.